# How to get list of files from a directory

Tags: c#, image

Hi I am having a hard time searching for this problem. I know how to open a folder from my c# application, for that I have used below code

```
string name = lstEmployees.Text;
Process.Start(@"H:\"+name);
```

but I want to know how to get the list of files from the folder or directory using c#. Can anyone please help me in this matter?

Comment: Process.Start opens the windows explorer, what I'm trying to do is to open it inside the c# window either a panel as container or anything

Comment: i'm sorry that comment was supposed to answers a comment also, but the comment i replied to was deleted

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to open current directory then

```
Process.Start("explorer.exe", System.AppDomain.CurrentDomain.BaseDirectory);
```

or others directory

```
string name = lstEmployees.Text;
Process.Start("explorer.exe", name);
```

**Update**

if you want to get all the file from a top level drive like C,D,E then use this

```
var fileList = new DirectoryInfo(@"D:\").GetFiles("*.*", SearchOption.TopDirectoryOnly);

foreach (var fileInfo in fileList)
   {
       MessageBox.Show(fileInfo.ToString());
   }
```

and if you want to get files from a folder then

```
var fileList = new DirectoryInfo(@"D:\folder").GetFiles("*.*", SearchOption.AllDirectories);

foreach (var fileInfo in fileList)
   {
       MessageBox.Show(fileInfo.ToString());
   }
```

Hope this is what you want

Comment: hi yes i've got it, but the problem is it will open the windows explorer, what i want to do is to create a container that contains the folder, check the image

Comment: so you want to get all the files in a location ?

Comment: yup...its very hard to explain, the image i think will make it clearer

Comment: ok I am editing my answer wait a minute

Comment: ok see my update by this you can get all file a from a drive or directory and after that you can use it anywhre like listview or something to show like your image

Comment: hi the solution you give just retrieve the files...what i want is to some like create a file explorer inside the window

Comment: this is a big solution what do you want, I have show you how to get all the files. After get all the files you can assign them in a listview control inside you form which will show all the files in your selected ditectory like `listBox1.Items.Add(fileInfo.ToString())`

Answer (score 0):

You can add a datagridview to your screen and then use

```
var files  = Directory.GetFiles(mypath).Select(x => new FileInfo(x)).ToList();
dataGridView1.DataSource = files;
```

Comment: wow, great answer, but then datagrid may not be the best output, but i like the idea

Comment: No but its a quick hash to show you a starting point